# chrome dev tools - view page as it rendered?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, console, preview

I'm trying to debug a response sent by an ajax request, I use the "network" section in chrome dev tools.
I can see the page in the "preview" after I click the request, but I only see the page as plain text.
I want to see the page as it will be rendered by the browser, with JS and CSS.   I remember I did that in older versions of chrome, so I know it is possible.

Comment: What is being sent from ajax mall?

Comment: *call it was autocomplete error

Comment: What sent is a django server error page, I'm trying to view the local vars (requires javascript).